# Laravel 5.3 cannot reset password

Tags: php, laravel, email, password-recovery

I'm running a local project on Wamp using the built-in laravel auth system, but suddenly my reset password doesn't work, I get this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
"
```

I have no idea what this means.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That mean's that you need to review your mail configuration. What kind of mailing system are you using in your development environment? I'm using mailtrap.io for my development environment

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to send an e-mail through SMTP, but fails to authenticate with the mailserver. Have you checked https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail and configured the mail settings in your `.env` file?

Comment: I don't know what the env settings should be, its like this now:

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: signed up on mailtrap and change the env: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**
MAIL_PASSWORD=**

but this still doesnt work

Comment: I think your config should look like, I thought port 2525 doesn't use encryption, but I might be wrong: MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=[MAILTRAP_USERNAME]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[MAILTRAP_PASSWORD]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: somehow i fixed it by setting encryption to tls, running config:cache and restarting wamp. Thanks anyways !